# Release resource being held by another process

Tags: python, simpy

In SimPy, if I've process `a`, `b` and resource `r` and do:

```
yield request, self, r #request done in process a
```

How can I release the resource from process b?

```
yield release, a, r #release done in b (being a an instance of class a), doesn't work
```

I've also tried:

```
r.activeQ.remove(a)
```

And it actually removes from the active queue, however it won't do all the implicit steps made when doing a `yield` and it turns out to be kind of pointless.

Can it be done? if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my problem was process `b` was actually inactive and therefore any `yield` call would be unsuccessful.

A workaround I came up with was

```
activate(a, a.function()) #called from process b
```

Where

```
class a(Process):
    def function(self):
        yield release, self, r
        yield passivate, self
```

Hope this can help anyone out there having the same problem.